# Dependency Injection based on a condition

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm using Google Guice for dependency injection. Suppose I have the following:

```
public interface Payment {
    public void pay();
}

public class PaymentCardImpl implements Payment {
    public void pay() {
        System.out.println("I pay with a card");
    }
}

public class PaymentCashImpl implements Payment {
    public void pay() {
        System.out.println("I pay cash");
    }
}

public class Order {

    private Payment payment;

    @Inject
    public Order(Payment payment){
        this.payment=payment;
    }

    public void finishOrder(){
        this.payment.pay();
    }
}
```

Following on from this, is a very simple module for binding, like so:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Payment.class).to(PaymentCashImpl.class);
    }
}
```

As you can see, a `Payment` instance is injected into the Order constructor. This is done in the `MyModule` class and overall is really cool.

My main looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyModule module = new MyModule();
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
    Order order = injector.getInstance(Order.class);
    order.finishOrder();
}
```

What I can't see however, is how I could incorporate some way to conditionally bind either a `PaymentCardImpl` ***or*** a `PaymentCashImpl` instance to the `Order` constructor.

Let's say for example, that the order was an 'online' order. I would then need to this:

```
bind(Payment.class).to(PaymentCardImpl.class);
```

What's the best way to do this? I'm new to dependency injection.

Comment: When do you know _which_ implementation you need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can annotate which one you want to inject. If you do a named binding it will resolve the issue.

See below:

```
bind(Payment.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Card")).to(PaymentCardImpl.class);

bind(Payment.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Cash")).to(PaymentCashImpl.class);
```

Then where you want to inject you do:

```
@Named("Cash") Payment payment
```

or:

```
@Named("Card") Payment payment
```

Comment: +1 I'm going to mark this as the best answer as this is the approach I used in the end. It offered me the greatest flexibility.

Comment: But we will still need a PaymentProvider (factory) which will provide the Payment concrete implementation based upon a condition. Let me know if there's any other way around this ?

Answer (score 12):

Dependency injection is useful for creating `service` style objects.  These have the following characteristics:-

- multiple implementations are likely,
- heavy on behaviour,
- internal state is limited to their dependencies and they are generally not mutable
- would map to an actor in the real world (e.g. cashier), rather than a thing

Based on this, `Payment` is a service object.  I would rename it `PaymentService` to distinguish it from the ledger entry you may store about a payment (which would be a value object).

You example does not show much about what the `Order` class, does, but I assume it would hold information like some line items, delivery address and total amount.  This is a `value` object.  It represents a thing in the business domain.

Value objects are heavy on state, and lighter on behaviour.  Multiple implementations are possible, but you are less likely to want to replace one implementation with another.

Value objects are not created by your dependency injection framework.  They are created by your business logic code.  In your example, you are creating all the objects using Guice.  I expect in reality you would need to create the `Order` at run-time based on user input.

Service objects can depend on value objects, but never the other way around.  I think you should be looking to implement:

`checkoutService.payfor( order, method );`

and not `order.finishOrder( method )`

Within the `CheckoutService` class, you could choose an approriate `PaymentService` and pass the `order` to it.  The `CheckoutService` would take as constructor arguments `PaymentCardPaymentService` (equivalent to your PaymentCardImpl) and `CashPaymentService` (equivalent to your PaymentCashImpl).

Comment: Great answer, thanks for this. In my actual scenario, I'm using SOAP service that does not have any internal state, so the characteristics you outline resonate with what I need. Nevertheless, you've given me some nice tips! If you could provide a worked example of what you outline, this would be very helpful also. Thanks

Comment: What is actually a SOAP service?  Is it the payment implementations?  Wouldn't they have some state like URL, proxy configuration, etc? I don't know Guice so I can't provide an example but I think you need to get your classes straight first and then the other respondants answers are useful.

Answer (score 9):

I know why you want to do this. But I would not mix up construction code (which is dependency injection configuration) with business logic. If you do that, your business logic might not be understandable anymore. And to me it seems, that your conditional injection depends on the situation, i.e. an input from a user interface.

So why not just inject both and make the condition explicit? I'd prefer that. An example  app:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyModule module = new MyModule();
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
    Order order = injector.getInstance(Order.class);
    order.finishOrder(PaymentMethod.CARD);
  }
}

public class PaymentProvider {
  private final Payment cashPayment, cardPayment;

  @Inject
  public PaymentProvider(CardPayment cardPayment, CashPayment cashPayment) {
    this.cardPayment = cardPayment;
    this.cashPayment = cashPayment;
  }

  public Payment getPaymentByMethod(PaymentMethod method) {
    switch (method) {
      case CARD:
        return cardPayment;
      case CASH:
        return cashPayment;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unkown payment method: " + method);
    }
  }
}

public enum PaymentMethod { CASH, CARD }

public class Order {
  private final PaymentProvider paymentProvider;

  @Inject
  public Order(PaymentProvider paymentProvider) {
    this.paymentProvider = paymentProvider;
  }

  public void finishOrder(PaymentMethod method) {
    paymentProvider.getPaymentByMethod(method).pay();
  }
}
```

Still for your own practise: The Payment stuff. You do not need any Guice code in there. The rest is done by Guice automagically. If you start using interfaces you would have start to use bindings as described here: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted. But if you do not have any interfaces, the construction is done without any configuration. The @Inject annotations are enough.

Of course this is just an example design. But it shows how easy it is to setup a nicely decoupled Java app with Guice.

Comment: You can't inject both. If I try this, I get an exception from Guice. I can only do one binding. Can you provide an example of what you mean? I think I may be missing the point of Dependency Injection here. I'm thinking of runtime binding.

Comment: It's not a good abstraction but the most naive way would be this (post edited)

Comment: Thanks for the example. When you say "inject all the possible payment methods into it", what exactly do you mean here? Thanks

Comment: I added an almost-complete example. Hope that helps. Best, Stefan

Comment: What would the bindings in the `configure` method above look like in order to inject 2 `CardPayment` instances into the `PaymentProvider` class? Thanks

Comment: Why would you do that? Just change the constructor to PaymentProvider(CardPayment cardPayment1, CardPayment cardPayment2). If you would differentiate Visa from Master, again you could just use the concrete implementations like VisaCardPayment card1, MasterCardPayment card2. The principle is pretty general

Answer (score 7):

Using [MapBinder](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings) extension you can get injected with several bindings contained in a `Map`. Then it's a matter of implementation which one to use.

You will need a key, in your case that could be a `String` or `Enumeration` and bind all `Payment` implementations to the appropriate keys:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    // this one aggregates all bindings and could be further annotated if you
    // need several maps with same key/value types
    MapBinder<String, Payment> mapBinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(),
      String.class, Payment.class);

    // simple binding of PaymentCashImpl to 'cash' key
    mapBinder.addBinding("cash").to(PaymentCashImpl.class);

    // you can scope during binding or using @Singleton annotation on implementations
    mapBinder.addBinding("card").to(PaymentCardImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
  }
}
```

Then in `Order` you get injected with the whole map and decide which implementation to use:

```
public class Order {
  @Inject
  Map<String, Provider<Payment>> paymentProcessors;

  public void finishOrder(String paymentMethod) {
    if (!paymentProcessors.containsKey(paymentMethod)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown payment method " + paymentMethod);
    }
    Payment paymentProcessor = paymentProcessors.get(paymentMethod).get();

    // do your stuff...
    paymentProcessor.pay();
  }
}
```

**Note:** Injecting providers doesn't work with `javax.inject.Provider`, you need to use `com.google.inject.Provider`.

By injecting providers instead of instances you can achieve lazy instantiation and different instantiation policies per implementation. Like in the example above the `PaymentCardImpl` is singleton, while the other is created each time. You can use guice [scopes](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Scopes) to control the lifespan, or even implement your own provider to accomplish something else.